# DOM/PDF error - Non-static method Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF::download() should not be called statically

Tags: laravel, dompdf

My Controller is this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade as PDF;
class PrintPDF extends Controller
{
    
    public function print(){
       $details =['title' => 'test'];
       $pdf = PDF::loadView('textDoc', $details);
       return $pdf::download('this.pdf');
    }
}
```

My routes

```
Route::get('/print', 'PrintPDF@print');
```

when accessing localhost/print I get an error

> Non-static method Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF::download() should not be called
> statically

I followed the install instructions on their site. I have tried to change my controller adding use PDF, instead of use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade as PDF; Yet the error persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make the function call like this

```
return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
```

Answer (score 19):

**This happens because you are namespacing the wrong PDF class.
You are namespacing Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF and try to use this class as "Facade" which is wrong.**

*To solve your problem
Set namespace to the facade:*

```
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade as PDF;
```

*Function Should be like this*

```
   $details =['title' => 'test'];
   $pdf = PDF::loadView('Your view path', $details);
```

*You can download directly using download method*

```
   return $pdf->dowload('test.pdf');
```

*or you can save in specific directory of your project*

```
   return $pdf->save('path of your directory/filename.pdf');
```

This worked for me....